# How to use methods from two classes in eachother in Java?

Tags: java

I've been looking around and I only found one answer which wasn't clear enough, to me at least.

I am building a very basic chat application with a GUI and I have separated the GUI from the connection stuff. Now I need to call one method from GUI in server class and vice versa. But I don't quite understand how to do it (even with "this"). Here's what a part of code looks like (this is a class named server_frame):

```
textField.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        srv.sendData(arg0.getActionCommand());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    textField.setText("");
                }
            }
            );
```

This is a code from server_frame, srv is an object from the other class (server) which contains sendData method, and I probably didn't define it correctly so hopefully someone could make a definition of it.

On the other side class server from which object srv was made contains method using JTextArea displayArea from server_frame in this code:

```
private void displayMessage(final String message){
    sf = new server_frame();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            sf.displayArea.append(message);
        }
    }
            );
}
```

Yet again sf is an object made of server_frame and yet again probably missdefined :)

Hopefully that was clear enough, sadly I tried the searching but it just didn't give me the results I was looking for, if you need any more info I will gladly add it!

Thanks for reading,

Mr.P.

P.S. Please don't mind if I made terminology mishaps, I am still quite new to java and open to any corrections!

Comment: If I correctly understand, you can pass some GUI class instance to the server method, like `srv.sendData(arg0.getActionCommand(), displayArea);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some class must be building both of these objects--the GUI and the server--and it should make each aware of the other. For example, say the main class is `ServerApplication`. I'll use standard Java convention of starting class names with an uppercase letter for clarity.

```
class ServerApplication {
    Server server;
    ServerFrame gui;

    public static void main(String []) {
        server = new Server(...);
        gui = new ServerFrame(server);
        server.setGui(gui);
    }
}
```

Each class should store the reference to the other as well.

```
class Server {
    ServerFrame gui;

    public void setGui(ServerFrame gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    ...
}

class ServerFrame extends JFrame {
    Server server;

    public ServerFrame(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I am a bit embarrassed about forgetting the name conventions, but anyway this solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the ClassName.this.methodName syntax. this in those actionlisteners refer to the anonymous class you created. If you used the above syntax you would be referencing the class that contains the anonymous class.

Or if you are looking for a private field in the class, you would do ClassName.this.privateField